# Problematic proof by contradiction

Tags: first-order-logic

I am trying prove this implication, however I keep getting stuck and I cannot figure out where to go next. I know I will need to do a proof by contradiction.

The steps I already took are:

1. {¬∀ to ∃} (∃i : 0≤i < n : ¬(b[i]))
2. {∃ Elimination} [Some K] 0≤k < n ∧ ¬b[k]

I have to prove this:

```
¬(∀i : 0≤i < n : b[i]) ∧ (∀i : j≤i < n : b[i])
⇒
¬(∀i : 0≤i < j : b[i])
```

I feel like I should put get a false by getting a b[k] ∧ ¬b[k]. But I cannot figure out how to get that.

Comment: You sure this is not better suited on [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: Will look there too. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question

Answer (score 0):

You can use implication elimination:

¬(∀i : 0≤i < n : b[i]) ∧ (∀i : j≤i < n : b[i])
⇒
¬(∀i : 0≤i < j : b[i])

≡ ¬[¬(∀i : 0≤i < n : b[i]) ∧ (∀i : j≤i < n : b[i])] ∨ ¬(∀i : 0≤i < j : b[i])

≡ (∀i : 0≤i < n : b[i]) ∨ ¬(∀i : j≤i < n : b[i]) ∨ ¬(∀i : 0≤i < j : b[i])

≡ (∀i : 0≤i < n : b[i]) ∨ (∃i : j≤i < n : ¬b[i]) ∨ (∃i : 0≤i < j : ¬b[i])

Then you can split the first one:

≡ [ (∀i : 0≤i < j : b[i]) ∧ (∀i : j≤i < n : b[i]) ] ∨ (∃i : j≤i < n : ¬b[i]) ∨ (∃i : 0≤i < j : ¬b[i])

≡ [ (∀i : 0≤i < j : b[i]) ∧ (∀i : j≤i < n : b[i]) ] ∨ ¬(∀i : j≤i < n : b[i]) ∨ ¬(∀i : 0≤i < j : b[i])

≡ [ (∀i : 0≤i < j : b[i]) ∧ (∀i : j≤i < n : b[i]) ] ∨ ¬[ (∀i : j≤i < n : b[i]) ∧ (∀i : 0≤i < j : b[i]) ]

≡ A ∨ ¬A

≡ True